# Kotlin read/import Map from txt.file

Tags: kotlin

I am working on a learning project, that is supposed to import and export Flashcards to a txt.file which is later supposed to be used in questioning.

Currently, I am stuck on the import part and the research I did is not really working, because I am not really getting it.

I have this overall map where I save the term: definition in a map

```
private var flashCardMap = mutableMapOf<String, String>()
```

Then I have this export function

```
    private fun export() {
        println("File name:")
        scan.nextLine()
        val fileName = scan.nextLine()
        val myFile = File(fileName)
        try {
            myFile.bufferedWriter().use { out->
                flashCardMap.forEach {
                    out.write("${it.key}:${it.value}\n")
                } }
            println("${flashCardMap.size} cards have been saved.")
        } catch (e: FileNotFoundException) {
            println("File not Found.")
        }
    }
```

which exports all the cards I defined earlier in a txt. file like this with one or more Flashcard (Card = Definition)

```
key:value
```

AND here is where I am stuck. I try to import a .txt file and the including map but it does not work. It Is supposed to import the map and tell me how many Cards where imported and the add them to my current flashcardmap with which I am working in this session. Here is what I tried:

```
    private fun import() {
        println("File name:")
        scan.nextLine()
        val fileName = scan.nextLine()
        val myFile = File("$fileName")
        try {
            val importMap =
            myFile.readLines().chunked(2) {
                it[0] to it[1]
            }.toMap()
            println("${importMap.size} cards have been loaded.")
            flashCardMap.putAll(importMap)
        } catch (e: FileNotFoundException) {
            println("File not Found.")
        }
    }
```

Comment: What kind of issue are you experiencing? Are you getting an exception, or are you getting only a subset of the data you'd like to read, or something else?

Comment: What format do you want the file to be?  Everything on one line (`key=value, key=value…`)?  One line per entry (`key=value`, `key=value`…)?  One line per value (`key`, `value`, `key`, `value`…)?  Something else?  — Right now your export is writing (almost) one of those, but your import is trying to read another.

Comment: Thank your for taking your time. It get an empty Map when I import from a file, with no key value pairs. What I want is to export a my map with key, value pairs (Flashcards) as a txt file and later import that exact same map to use in my programm again and add them to the flashCardMap. Do you understand what I mean? :)

Comment: You haven't answered my question.  (Doing should show you where your problem is.)

Comment: @gidds I had not thought about this. I modified my export function (see above) so that I export key:value \n . So each key-value pair in a new line. Now my next step would be to import via myFile.forEachLine and somehow split each pair by the delimiter ":" and assign the keys and values to my import map. Im just not sure how to write it in code

Comment: It sounds like you're mostly there.  You can use the [`split()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/split.html) method to split a string at a delimiter such as `:`.

Comment: Why are you doing `scan.nextLine()` before `val fileName = scan.nextLine()` ?

Comment: @gidds thank you I solved it. (although I am not sure this is the best solution, it is working)<br/>
``` 
            val importList = myFile.readLines()
            val importMap = importList
                    .map { it.split(":") }
                    .map { it.first() to it.last() }
                    .toMap()
            println("${importMap.size} cards have been loaded.")
            flashCardMap.putAll(importMap)
```

Comment: @NikolaiShevchenko when I did not do it it just skipped and the user could not input anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's actually so many ways to serialize structured data to a file, but since your example uses the `key:value` format, separated by new-lines, we'll stick with that.

This class should suit your needs.  But it's pretty simplistic, and lacks any sort of error handling.

```
class Serializer(private val filePath: Path, private val delimiter: String = ":") {

    fun export(data: Map<String, String>) {
        filePath.toFile().writer().use { writer ->
            for ((key, value) in data) {
                writer.write("$key$delimiter$value\n")
            }
        }
    }

    fun import(): Map<String, String> {
        val data = mutableMapOf<String, String>()

        filePath.toFile().reader().use { reader ->
            reader.forEachLine { line ->
                val (key, value) = line.split(delimiter)
                data[key] = value
            }
        }

        return data
    }
}
```

If you want to leverage a mature format, then the built-in `java.util.Properties` class can make things even easier.  The only gotcha is that it uses a `=` delimiter by default, but it's supposed to be able to read a `:` delimiter too.

```
class PropertiesSerializer(private val filePath: Path) {

    fun export(data: Map<String, String>) {
        val props = Properties()

        for ((key, value) in data) {
            props[key] = value
        }

        filePath.toFile().outputStream().use { stream ->
            props.store(stream, null)
        }
    }

    fun import(): Map<String, String> {
        val props = Properties()

        filePath.toFile().inputStream().use { stream ->
            props.load(stream)
        }

        return props
                .map { (key, value) -> key.toString() to value.toString() }
                .toMap()
    }
}
```